# I want to completely uninstall rails. How do I reconcile these observations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Under MacOs 14.2.1:

```
Person@MacBook-Pro proj % rails -v
Rails 7.1.2

Person@MacBook-Pro proj % gem uninstall rails
Gem 'rails' is not installed

Person@MacBook-Pro proj % gem list | grep rails
jquery-rails (2.3.0)
rails-dom-testing (2.2.0)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.6.0)
rails-i18n (0.7.4)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
```

Not exactly sure how I got to this point.  Is there a best practice for how to remove Rails 7.1.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You've asked two questions, so here's the answer to one of them.

To explain the various rails-related gems still present: when you uninstall a package it does not uninstall its dependencies. You need to do that manually, or just leave them because they're innocuous.

To the issue of being able to run `rails -v` and yet `gem` tells you Rails is uninstalled. Hard to imagine, but are those two commands at different paths? Run `which rails` and `which gem` and add the output to your question.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to share this good answer.  In the intervening week, I have made a number of changes to my shell profile and $path.  I don't think I can produce a valid response to your excellent request.  FWIW, I decided to remove RVM and install rbenv.  I am not blaming RMV, but things are working as expected now.  Thanks again.